# How to change variable names inside array php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Ok so I have been struggling with this for hours now and I cannot seem to figure out what I'm trying to do. I have an array with many percent values placed inside and I'm printing out the first 5 of them. The $percent variables are acquired through similar_text

```
$array=array($percent12, $percent13, $percent14,
    $percent15, $percent16, $percent17,
    $percent18, $percent19, $percent110,
    $percent111, $percent112, $percent113,
    $percent114, $percent115, $percent116,
    $percent117, $percent118, $percent119,
    $percent120);

print_r(array_slice($array,0,5));
```

and it outputs like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 36.015505697169 [1] => 2.4181626187962 [2] => 2.4181626187962 [3] => 5.2153134902083 [4] => 100 )
```

So what i'm trying to figure out here is if it's possible to print the results of my array as they are listed above. example output would look like this:

```
Array ( [percent12] => 36.015505697169 [percent13] => 2.4181626187962 [percent14] => 2.4181626187962 [percent15] => 5.2153134902083 [percent16] => 100 )
```

i feel like this isn't possible, but if not, is there a way to assign the

```
[0]=> 36.015505697169 [1]=> 2.4181626187962
```

...etc to output something else say like:

```
[web0]=> 36.015505697169 [web1] => 2.4181626187962
```

Please help!! It's driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it an associative array:

```
$array=array('percent12' => $percent12, 
             'percent13' => $percent13,
             ...);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for thank you so much! I tried this approach before but couldn't get it to work for some reason, but I got it working now! Thank you so much it's greatly appreacited!!

Comment: Maybe something you can also help me out with.. as soon as I used an r_sort on my array it went back to how it was acting before. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Use `arsort` to sort an associative array and keep the key associations.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Basically you're just going to setup your new array with the keys, and pass in your current array for the values, thus creating a new array with the keys you want in the right place.

Comment: Once you're done, just unset the arrays you don't need and free up a little memory ;)

Comment: This worked great for me thanks! I was actually looking for more of the approach with the associative arrays, but this worked great too thank you so much!!!!

Comment: `array_combine` is just another way to create an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$myArr = array_slice($array,0,5);
$i = 0;
foreach($myArr as $key => $value) {
   $newArr['web'.$i++] = $value;
}
print_r($newArr);
```